# The efficient way to get a list of objects that are not in the database in Java

Tags: java, sql

Suppose I have a list of objects (ArrayList objects) and a db table for the objects, I want to find the objects which has not been stored in the my database. The objects are identified by their "id". I can think of two solutions but I do not know which one is more efficient.

The first solution I think of is to construct one db query to get all objects existed in the db, and loop through the existed objects to determine the ones that is not in the db

```
ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(MyObject o in  objects){
    ids.add(o.getId());
}

//I use sugar orm on Android, raw query can be seen as 
// "select * from my_object where id in [ id1,id2,id3 .....  ]"
List<MyObjectRow> unwanted_objects = MyObject.find("id in (?,?,?,?,.....)",ids);

//remove the query results from the original arraylist
for(MyObjectRow o in  unwanted_objects){
     for(MyObject o1 in  objects){
         if(o1.getId() == o.getId()) objects.remove(o1);

     }
}
```

The second solution is to query existence of every object in db, and add non-existed object to result array

```
ArrayList<MyObject> result_objects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

boolean exist = false
for(MyObject o in  objects){
       exist = MyObject.find("EXIST( select 1 from my_object where id = ?)", o.getId());
       if(!exist){
           result_objects.add(o);
       }
}
```

The first solution only require one query, but when loop through all founded objects, the complexity become O(n*n)

The second solution constructs n db querys, but it only has a complexity of O(n)

Which one may be better in terms of performance?

Comment: Use option 1 and a `Set<MyObject>` or `Map<Integer, MyObject>` instead of `List<MyObject>` to change it to O(n).

Comment: Vote up @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: Thanks guys for the simple but great solution

Comment: How many records are you going to search? I don't know if there is some limitation in "in clause", but if you are going to search millions of objects, it won't work at all. May be the best solution will be join both solutions. Search using "in clause", but just a limited number os objects (let's say 1000 at most), and looping until all objects have been searched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use option 1 with a change to use a `Map<Integer, MyObject>` to improve the performance of the removal of query results from the original list:

```
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Map<Integer, MyObject> mapToInsert = new HashMap<Integer, MyObject>();
for(MyObject o in  objects) {
    //add the ids of the objects to possibly insert
    ids.add(o.getId());
    //using the id of the object as the key in the map
    mapToInsert.put(o.getId(), o);
}

//retrieve the ids of the elements that already exist in database
List<MyObjectRow> unwanted_objects = MyObject.find("id in (?,?,?,?,.....)",ids);

//remove the query results from the map, not the list
for(MyObjectRow o in unwanted_objects){
     mapToInsert.remove(o.getId());
}

//insert the values that still exist in mapToInsert
Collection<MyObject> valuesToInsert = mapToInsert.values();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't know the efficiency of the database operations. If the database is a b-tree under the hood that query could take O(log n). If your indices aren't set up correctly, you may be looking at o(n) performance for that query. Your measurement of efficiency here is also ignoring any transaction costs: the cost to initiation a connection with, process the query, and close the connection to the database. This is a 'fixed' cost, and I wouldn't want to do that in a loop if i didn't have to.

Go with the first solution.

Comment: You could open the connection before the loop, execute the necessary statements and then close the connection after the loop and the impact is less than the scenario you describe. Option 1 by itself is not the right approach either but it's better than option 2.

Comment: yeah but i have no idea what the ORM he's using is doing under the hood.

Comment: I don't know either and no matter what orm or framework on top of JDBC you use, the concepts remain the same